# Starter Site Data Connection not showing VS 2015

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015

Just starting to learn ASP.NET, so I apologize for the basic question. Using VS 2015 Community.

I just created a website (ASP.NET Web Site (Razor v3)) and am walking through a tutorial. The video that I am watching mentions that by double clicking on the "StarterSite.sdf" under App_Data should bring up the Server Explorer, and should look like below.

[image: Desired Data Connection Tree]

However, in my machine there is no data connection shown to the StarterSite, and when I try to add a connection, it says that the .sdf format is not a valid db format file.

I haven't modified anything in any of the files. Also, I should add that when I double click the "StarterSite.sdf" file under App_Data it opens it like it does a code page, and it appears to just be a lot of Hex stuff.